# Rambam on color certainty of tekheleth

Tags: halacha, rambam, color, safek, techeles

According to a questioner on [this page](http://tekhelet.com/tekhelet/ask-ptil-tekhelet/), the Rambam in the *Pirush HaMishna* contradicts the Rambam in *Hilchoth Tzitzith* regarding whether we can dye *tekheleth* due to uncertainty about the color. Where are these references specifically?

Comment: On Rambam's understanding of the color of tekhelet see http://www.torahmusings.com/2017/06/testament-true-tekhelet/ under the Rambam header

Answer (score 1):

The relevant statement is in his [Pirush HaMishnayos 4:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37947&st=&pgnum=183&hilite=):

> ואינו נמצא בידינו היום לפי שאין אנו יודעים לצובעו שאין כל מין תכלת בצמר נקרא תכלת אלא תכלת ידועה שאי אפשר לעשותה היום ועל כן אנו עושים בלבן לבדו
>
> And [Techeiles] is not found in our hands today because we do not know how to dye it because not all types of Techeiles in wool are called Techeiles except for the known Techeiles that is impossible to make today. Therefore we make white [i.e. regular Tzitzis undyed] only.

The relevant chapter in Hilchos Tzitzis is [chapter 2](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2402.htm). He says nothing which contradicts the above, nor does he address it. In Halacha 1 he says in part:

> והתכלת האמורה בציצית, צריך שתהא צביעתה צביעה ידועה
>
> The Techeiles said about Tzitzis, its dye has to be from a known dye.

And in Halacha 9 he says in part:

> שאינה מצויה בכל מקום ולא בכל זמן, מפני הצבע שאמרנו
>
> [Techeiles] is not found in every place nor at every time, because of the dye which we spoke about.

So there is nothing in Hilchos Tzitzis which contradicts the Pirush HaMishnayos.

Comment: Why translate צבע/צביעה as 'dye' and not 'color'?